# miniMax-Algorithm is not working properly

Tags: java, tic-tac-toe, minimax

**Update3:**
I've fixed it. In the end it was a couple of small mistakes (see Update 1 and Update2) and the last mistake was pretty crucial:

```
public static List<int[]> generateMoves() {
    List<int[]> possibleMoves = new ArrayList<int[]>();

    if (notWon() == false) {
        return possibleMoves;
    }
    for (int row = 0; row < 3; ++row) {
        for (int col = 0; col < 3; ++col) {
            if (gameBoard[row][col] == 0) {
                possibleMoves.add(new int[]{row, col});
            }
        }
    }
    return possibleMoves;
}
```

I did a big mistake here, before the row and col was iterating from 0 to 2, which meant that the computer effectively only had a 2x2 field to work with. This explained his poor placement. **Now the algorithm works perfectly and I'm a happy snowflake.**

---

**Update2:**
I've changed the conditional operator:
**from**

```
int maxValue = (player == computerTurn) ? Integer.MAX_VALUE : Integer.MIN_VALUE;
```

**to**

```
int maxValue = (player == computerTurn) ? Integer.MIN_VALUE : Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```

Now the computer does make several individual turns (changes the row and col values), but it is not correctly finding a winning game sate (example:)

```
 |   |
```

---

```
 |   |
```

---

```
 |   |
```

---

1evaluation-value
1row
1col

```
 |   |
```

---

```
 |  X|
```

---

```
 |   |
```

---

Player O, please enter a row (1-3):3
Player O, please enter a column (1-3):3

```
 |   |
```

---

```
 |  X|
```

---

```
 |   |  O
```

---

19evaluation-value
0row
0col

```
X|   |
```

---

```
 |  X|
```

---

```
 |   |  O
```

---

Player O, please enter a row (1-3):3
Player O, please enter a column (1-3):2

```
X|   |
```

---

```
 |  X|
```

---

```
 |  O|  O
```

---

10evaluation-value
1row
0col

```
X|   |
```

---

```
X|  X|
```

---

```
 |  O|  O
```

---

Player O, please enter a row (1-3):2
Player O, please enter a column (1-3):3

```
X|   |
```

---

```
X|  X|  O
```

---

```
 |  O|  O
```

---

1evaluation-value
0row
1col

```
X|  X|
```

---

```
X|  X|  O
```

---

```
 |  O|  O
```

---

Player O, please enter a row (1-3):1
Player O, please enter a column (1-3):3

```
X|  X|  O
```

---

```
X|  X|  O
```

---

```
 |  O|  O
```

---

Player   has won!
Player   has won!

---- The Game is OVER ---

Process finished with exit code 0

**Update:**
Okay, I've made three printout's at the computerInput method.

```
 System.out.println(bestMove[0] + "evaluation-value");
 System.out.println(bestMove[1]+ "row");
 System.out.println(bestMove[2] + "col");
```

Here is the strange thing:
When the function is first called, it runs trough all minimax methods and evaluates the best value. However, it does not change the row and column (col) values which are initialized with row = 1, col = 1. If I change them too -1, -1 I get an "IndexOutOfBound Exception". This is further proof that these values somehow are not assigned with the proper values from the minimax-method. They are intended to be re-assigned with new values during the else-statement of the minimax-method. Interestingly the console always prints out the evaluated maxValue and row = 1, col = 1, which means that the computer repeatably sets his symbol into the same spot. This means every turn the computer makes is the same (1,1).

---

I'm currently working on a project which implements a game of "TicTacToe" with an inherit AI (using minimax). I'm currently having issues in finding a  semantic mistake, somehow the computer only makes his first turn which I defined as bestRow=1, bestCol=1. It seems like the algorithm **(miniMax)** in which he chose his best evaluated position is not working properly.

My algorithm uses a two dimensional array (gameBoard) with the type int. The computerInput = 1, playerInput = -1 and empty means 0. I have a second Array which I called consoleGameBoard, this board is from the type Char and converts the number entries of gameBoard using X for 1, O for -1 and Blank (' ') for 0.

This is my schema:

```
(0,0)(0,1)(0,2)

(1,0)(1,1)(1,2)

(2,0)(2,1)(2,2)
```

I'm really hoping that somebody can help me out...
**I think that the semantic failure is somewhere in the minimax-Method, as bestRow and bestCol don't seem to be updated, which means they stay on their initial assigned values (1,1) and the computer turn basically gets repeated the whole time.**

I've used this Tutorial as a guideline for the miniMax-Algorithm implemenation:
https://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaGame_TicTacToe_AI.html

The Board.class and Console.class are working completely fine, I can play the game with two human players without any problems. The semantic failure is somewhere in the MiniMax.class.

**My Code:**

```
public class MiniMax extends Board {

static int searchDepth = 4;
static int computerTurn = 1;
static int playerTurn = -1;


public static int[] miniMax(int player, int depth) {
    List<int[]> possibleMoves = generateMoves();

    /////////////// Condition //// if condition = true /// if false = false
    int maxValue = (player == computerTurn) ? Integer.MIN_VALUE : Integer.MAX_VALUE; //  // conditional operator
    int bestRow = 1;
    int bestCol = 1;
    int currentValue;

    if (depth == 0 || possibleMoves.isEmpty()) {
        maxValue = evaluate();
    } else {
        for (int[] tryMove : possibleMoves) { // for-each
            gameBoard[tryMove[0]][tryMove[1]] = player;
            if (player == computerTurn) {
                currentValue = miniMax(playerTurn, depth - 1)[0];
                if (currentValue > maxValue) {
                    maxValue = currentValue;
                    bestRow = tryMove[0];
                    bestCol = tryMove[1];

                }
            } else {
                currentValue = miniMax(computerTurn, depth - 1)[0];
                if (currentValue < maxValue) {
                    maxValue = currentValue;
                    bestRow = tryMove[0];
                    bestCol = tryMove[1];

                }
            }
            undoMove(tryMove);

        }
    }

    return new int[]{maxValue, bestRow, bestCol};
}

/**
 * This method evaluates the expected value for each of the 8 possible connections.
 * 3 rows, 3 columns and 2 diagonals. (See checkForWin for further clarification).
 * It is called by the MiniMax Algorithm in order to find the best move.
 *
 * @return score, a product of the inherit method call.
 * It connects all -1 or 1 entries and sums them up.
 * <p>
 * Possible (sum-)Values for "score":
 * +100(3x), +10(2x), +1(1x) for Computer-Connections.
 * -100(3x), -10(2x), -1 (1x) for Player-Connections.
 * 0 for EMPTY-Spots.
 * <p>
 * Schema:
 * (0,0) | (0,1) | (0,2)
 * (1,0) | (1,1) | (1,2)
 * (2,0) | (2,1) | (2,2)
 */
private static int evaluate() {
    int score = 0;
    score = score + connection(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2); // rowOne
    score = score + connection(1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2); // rowTwo
    score = score + connection(2, 0, 2, 1, 2, 2); // rowThree
    score = score + connection(0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0); // colOne
    score = score + connection(0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1); // colTwo
    score = score + connection(0, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2); // colThree
    score = score + connection(0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2); // diagonal 1
    score = score + connection(0, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0); // diagonal 2
    return score;
}

/**
 * This method shall only be called by the evaluate() Method!
 * It reviews all possible Spots by applying all the possible combinations from the evaluate() method.
 * This Method connects each entry and checks is the currently active player can increase his score.
 *
 * @param rowOne
 * @param colOne
 * @param rowTwo
 * @param colTwo
 * @param rowThree
 * @param colThree
 * @return Score, a value that determines the most effective move.
 */
private static int connection(int rowOne, int colOne, int rowTwo, int colTwo, int rowThree, int colThree) {
    int score = 0;
    // -1 = computerInput
    // 1 = userInput

    // First Spot
    if (gameBoard[rowOne][colOne] == computerTurn) { // First Spot = computerInput
        score = 1;
    } else if (gameBoard[rowOne][colOne] == playerTurn) { // First Spot = playerInput
        score = -1;
    }
    // Second Spot
    if (gameBoard[rowTwo][colTwo] == computerTurn) { // Second Spot = computerInput
        if (score == 1) { // TwoConnected for computerInput
            score = 10;
        } else if (score == -1) {
            return 0;
        } else { // Spot is EMPTY
            score = 1;
        }
    } else if (gameBoard[rowTwo][colTwo] == playerTurn) { // Second Spot = playerInput
        if (score == -1) { // TwoConnected for playerInput
            score = -10;
        } else if (score == 1) {
            return 0;
        } else { // Spot is EMPTY
            score = -1;
        }
    }
    // Third Spot
    if (gameBoard[rowThree][colThree] == computerTurn) { // Third Spot = computerInput
        if (score > 0) { // First Spot and/or Second Spot connected for computerInput
            score = score * 10;
        } else if (score < 0) {
            return 0;
        } else { // First Spot and Second Spot are EMPTY
            score = 1;
        }
    } else if (gameBoard[rowThree][colThree] == playerTurn) { // Third Spot = playerInput
        if (score < 0) { // First Spot and/or Second Spot connected for playerInput
            score = score * 10;
        } else if (score > 1) {
            return 0;
        } else { // First Spot and Second Spot are EMPTY
            score = -1;
        }
    }
    return score;
}

/**
 * Removes the last entry on the gameBoard by changing its value to zero (0) which means EMPTY.
 *
 * @param tryMove
 */

public static void undoMove(int[] tryMove) { 
    gameBoard[tryMove[0]][tryMove[1]] = 0;

}

/**
 * @return possibleMoves, a ArrayList which is discovering the currently possible gameBoard situations.
 */
public static List<int[]> generateMoves() { 
    List<int[]> possibleMoves = new ArrayList<int[]>();

    if (notWon() == false) {
        return possibleMoves;
    }
    for (int row = 0; row < 2; ++row) {
        for (int col = 0; col < 2; ++col) {
            if (gameBoard[row][col] == 0) {
                possibleMoves.add(new int[]{row, col});
            }
        }
    }
    return possibleMoves;
}

/**
 * This method calls minimax and returns the best move possible.
 *
 * @return bestMove, the result of the minimax algorithm (maxValue).
 */
public static int[] computerInput() {
    int[] bestMove = miniMax(computerTurn, searchDepth); // player, depth
    updateBoard(computerTurn, bestMove[1], bestMove[2]);
    convertToChar(bestMove[1], bestMove[2]);

    return new int[]{bestMove[1], bestMove[2]}; // 0 = maxValue, 1 = row, 2 = col.

}

}







public class Board {

public static int[][] gameBoard;
private static char[][] consoleGameBoard;
private static boolean continueGame = true;

/**
 * This is the constructor for the Board-Class
 */
public Board() {
    gameBoard = new int[3][3];
    consoleGameBoard = new char[3][3];

    for (int row = 0; row < gameBoard.length; row++) {
        Arrays.fill(gameBoard[row], 0);
    }
} // end of constructor

public void displayBoard() {
    for (int row = 0; row < consoleGameBoard.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < consoleGameBoard.length; col++) {
            System.out.print("\t" + consoleGameBoard[row][col]);
            if (col == 0 || col == 1)
                System.out.print("|");

        }
        System.out.print("\n_________________\n");
    }
}


public static boolean updateBoard(int player, int row, int col) {
    if (row >= 0 && row <= 2 && col >= 0 && col <= 2) {
        if (gameBoard[row][col] != 0) {
            return false;
        } else {
            gameBoard[row][col] = player;
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public void userInput(int player) {
    int row, col;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    do {

        System.out.printf("Player %s, please enter a row (1-3):", 'O');
        row = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.printf("Player %s, please enter a column (1-3):", 'O');
        col = keyboard.nextInt();

    } while (notValid(row, col));
    updateBoard(player, row - 1, col - 1);
    convertToChar(row - 1, col - 1);
}

public static boolean notValid(int row, int col) {
    if (row > 3 || row < 1 || col > 3 || col < 1 || !isBlank(row, col)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public static boolean notFull() {
    if (gameBoard[0][0] != 0 && gameBoard[0][1] != 0 && gameBoard[0][2] != 0 && gameBoard[1][0] != 0 && gameBoard[1][1] != 0 && gameBoard[1][2] != 0 &&
            gameBoard[2][0] != 0 && gameBoard[2][1] != 0 && gameBoard[2][2] != 0) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

public static boolean isBlank(int row, int col) {
    if (gameBoard[row - 1][col - 1] == 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        System.out.println(" -- INVALID! The Position is already taken! --");
        System.out.println(" ------------- Make another Move -------------");
        return false;
    }
}

public static boolean notWon() {
    // loop over each row and check for winner
    for (int row = 0; row < gameBoard.length; row++) {
        if (gameBoard[row][0] + gameBoard[row][1] +  gameBoard[row][2] == 3 ||gameBoard[row][0] + gameBoard[row][1] +  gameBoard[row][2] == -3) {
            System.out.println("Player " + consoleGameBoard[row][0] + " has won!");
            return continueGame = false;
        }
    }
    // loop over each column and check for winner
    for (int col = 0; col < gameBoard[0].length; col++) {
        if (gameBoard[0][col] + gameBoard[1][col] + gameBoard[2][col] == 3 || gameBoard[0][col] + gameBoard[1][col] + gameBoard[2][col] == -3) {
            System.out.println("Player " + consoleGameBoard[col][0] + " has won!");
            return continueGame = false;
        }
    }
    // check diagonal 1
    if (gameBoard[0][0] + gameBoard[1][1] + gameBoard[2][2] == 3 || gameBoard[0][0] + gameBoard[1][1] + gameBoard[2][2] == -3) {
        System.out.println("Player " + consoleGameBoard[0][0] + " has won!");
        return continueGame = false;
    }
    // check for diagonal 2
    if (gameBoard[2][0] + gameBoard[1][1] + gameBoard[0][2] == 3 ||gameBoard[2][0] + gameBoard[1][1] + gameBoard[0][2] == -3) {
        System.out.println("Player " + consoleGameBoard[2][0] + " has won!");
        return continueGame = false;
    } else {
        return continueGame = true;
    }
}

public static void convertToChar(int row, int col) {
    char X = 'X';
    char O = 'O';

    if (gameBoard[row][col] == 1) {
        consoleGameBoard[row][col] = X;
    } else {
        consoleGameBoard[row][col] = O;
    }
}


}







public class Console {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    structurePack.Board myGame = new structurePack.Board();

    int playerSwitch = 2;

    myGame.displayBoard();

    while (myGame.notWon() == true) {
        if (playerSwitch % 2 == 0)
            computePack.MiniMax.computerInput();
        else {
            myGame.userInput(-1);

        }
        playerSwitch++;
        System.out.println("\n");
        myGame.displayBoard();
        myGame.notWon();
        if (myGame.notWon() == false) {
            System.out.println("\n");
            System.out.println(" ---- The Game is OVER --- ");
            break;
        }
        myGame.notFull();
        if (myGame.notFull() == false) {
            System.out.println("\n");
            System.out.println(" --- This Game is a DRAW --- ");
            break;
        }  

    }

}
}
```

Comment: You should boil down the problem. My guess is that nobody is going to read all this code to find a single failure.

Comment: I'm currently trying to debug the minimax function-call to see if I can find the mistake. I agree, its a huge chunk of code... that's why its hard for me to find the issue.

Comment: Then you should be writing unit tests for smaller pieces.  Its faster than debugging one massive chunk of code.

Comment: plus one for unit tests.